# Issue with Converting data type for SQL Query Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I wrote the following query to union open items for production orders and inventory transfers. For the query from the OWOR Table ( After the union all)

I am getting an  error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

I tried converting the decimal (originally 6 characters to 2)

```
    Select  t15.ObjType, t15.shipdate, t15.docentry, t15.linenum, 
    t15.linestatus, t15.itemcode, t15.Dscription, t15.Quantity, t15.OpenQty, 
    t15.price, t15.Currency, t15.rate, t15.DiscPrcnt, t15.LineTotal, 
    t15.OpenSum, t15.VendorNum, t15.WhsCode,
    CASE
       WHEN t15.objtype = 67 THEN 'Inventory Transfer Request' 

       ELSE 'unknown'
     END AS Document_Type


    From wtq1 t15

    Union all

    Select t16.ObjType, T16.DueDate, T16.Docentry, T16.ProdName, 
    T16.ItemCode, T16.Uom, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), T16.PlannedQty), 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), T16.CmpltQty), T16.Status, T16.PostDate, 
    T16.CloseDate, T16.CreateDate, T16.UpdateDate, T16.Warehouse, 
    T16.JrnlMemo, T16.Priority, T16.Printed,

    CASE 
    WHEN t16.ObjType = 202 THEN 'Production Order'

    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS Document_Type

    From owor T16
```

Comment: You have a bunch of columns that do not match, as per their names.  So is t15.LineStatus the same type as t16.ItemCode? Or t15.linenum the same as t16.ProdName?  You might check the data type of each column you are union-ing together.

Answer (score 4):

When using `UNION` then all the corresponding columns must have the same data type. 
If not, then maybe there will be an implicit data type conversion if possible. 
In your case, by reading only the names of the columns, I can only guess that there are certain mismatches between columns:

```
t15.ObjType     t16.ObjType 
t15.shipdate    T16.DueDate 
t15.docentry    T16.Docentry 
t15.linenum     T16.ProdName 
t15.linestatus  T16.ItemCode 
t15.itemcode    T16.Uom 
t15.Dscription  CONVERT(DECIMAL(182) T16.PlannedQty) 
t15.Quantity    CONVERT(DECIMAL(182) T16.CmpltQty) 
t15.OpenQty     T16.Status 
t15.price       T16.PostDate 
t15.Currency    T16.CloseDate 
t15.rate        T16.CreateDate 
t15.DiscPrcnt   T16.UpdateDate 
t15.LineTotal   T16.Warehouse 
t15.OpenSum     T16.JrnlMemo 
t15.VendorNum   T16.Priority 
t15.WhsCode     T16.Printed
```

Check them yourself, but I think that at least these pairs:

```
t15.OpenQty     T16.Status 
t15.price       T16.PostDate 
t15.Currency    T16.CloseDate 
t15.rate        T16.CreateDate 
t15.DiscPrcnt   T16.UpdateDate
```

are unmatchable, just like others too.